# Testing if association exists in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to using rspec, so hopefully I'm explaining this correctly.  I want to make sure my object is created and afterwards make sure that a related object with a `has_one` relationship is created.

So, my code would look like this in the model:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :scan_option

  validates_presence_of :name

  after_create :create_scan_option

  def create_scan_option
    self.scan_option.create!
  end
end
```

I have a Factory for a device:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  serial_number = SecureRandom.uuid.delete("-")

  factory :device do
    identifier serial_number
    name "Device 1"
    is_registered true
    timezone "America/Chicago"
  end
end
```

In my rspec model test I imagine the code would look like this:

```
RSpec.describe Device, :type => :model do
  it "creates a scan_option after_create" do
    subject = build(:device)
    # test whether the scan_option object was created and associated with the device?
  end
end
```

I'm not using `shoulda` or anything, just trying to understand Rspec better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
subject(:device) { Device.create(attributes_for(:device)) }

it 'has a scan option' do
  expect(device.scan_option).to be_present
end
```

I would use `Device.create` instead of `FactoryGirl.create` to ensure that the class itself creates the associated object and that it is not created by the factory.

Comment: is there a difference between `be_present` and just `be` as suggested in one of the answers?

Comment: `be_present` tests that calling `present?` on the `scan_option`returns `true`. Whereas [`be`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers) tests that `scan_option` is truthy  (not `nil` or `false`). In this example it doesn't really make a difference in the result, but IMO it reads much better with `be_present`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to save the device and then call the association and check it returns something

```
it "creates a scan_option after_create" do
    subject = build(:device)

    subject.save

    expect(subject.scan_option).to be
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Several Ways:

```
subject = build(:device)
expect(subject.scan_option).not_to be_nil
```

```
expect { build(:device) }.to change(ScanOption, :count).by(1)
```

It probably won't pass because you only built your factory.

In order for the callback to be executed you actually have to persist it in the database:

```
subject = create(:device)
```